# Video player suggestions similar to youtube player

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, youtube, html5-video

What is the best way to create a video player similar to the youtube video player in that after the video has played, it shows a collection of further videos to watch?

The videos are not hosted on youtube.

Generating the video suggestions is not a problem. The problem is displaying them in the player after the video finished playing in such a way that if the user clicks one of the suggestions, the selected video page is opened and played.

Can I do this in html5 or jquery or flash or something else?

Answer (score 0):

JWPlayer is a good HTML5 video player with a Flash fallback. It also has a decent API which supports related videos: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/addons/related-videos/22352/related-videos-reference-guide/.

There are a few license options too: http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/pricing/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in Flash.  You could use the FLVPlayback Component to play the original video.  Then use the Listener Class to listen for COMPLETE.  You could then place thumbnails for each of the related videos on top of the FLVPlayback Component - these would then load the new video into the component and the process would continue.

Check [this tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3flvplayback/) out for using the component and also the Listener Class for the component.